# how to call the c file with python

Tags: python

File "/Users/naveen/call /h.py", line 5, in 
a= subprocess.call("./a.out")
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 349, in call
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 947, in **init**
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 1819, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './a.out'

how to get the solution for error in this

Comment: Can you post your Python code, so we can check what the error may be. We need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here

Comment: I suggest you improve your question, add some examples, some code and make it more clear and add your source code, Have a look here => [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)